# Check-in / Check-out date loading issue in Bootstrap Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-datepicker

From the below code if i click on check-in date as june 17th 2014 and calendar will directly popup the check-out calendar as may 18th 2014 but i need that calendar popup to show june 17th 2014. Can anyone help me and below is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        var nowTemp = new Date();
        var now = (nowTemp.getMonth()+1)+'-'+ nowTemp.getDate()+'-'+ nowTemp.getFullYear();


        $('#sandbox-container .input-append.date').datepicker({
            orientation: "auto",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate:now
            }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
                $('#sandbox-container1 span').trigger('click');
                $('.input-append.date.span12').css({display:'block'}).show();
            }); 

        var nowTemp1 = new Date();
        var now1 = (nowTemp1.getMonth()+1)+'-'+ (nowTemp1.getDate()+1)+'-'+ nowTemp1.getFullYear();

        $('#sandbox-container1 .input-append.date').datepicker({
            orientation: "auto",
            autoclose: true,
            startDate:now1
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

```
<div id="sandbox-container" class="book_arriv_input f-left">
    <div data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date="12-12-2013" id="dp1" class="input-append date" >
        <input type="text" id="check_in" name="checkin_date_avail" class="span6"/>
        <span> 
            <div class="add-on calender" style="margin-left: -5px;">
                <i class="icon-th"></i>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<div id="sandbox-container1" class="book_arriv_input f-left">
    <div data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date="12-13-2013" id="dp2" class="input-append date">
        <input type="text" id="check_out" name="checkout_date_avail" class="span6"><span class="add-on calender" style="margin-left: -5px;"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: Consider formatting the code using 4-spaces or ` marks so it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

the second date is disabled on the 17th because now1 starts from one day after.
you can use now instead of now1.
Edit:
you can set the date on the checkout picker based on the checkin picker like this:

```
picker1 = $('#sandbox-container1 .input-append.date').datepicker()
picker1.data('datepicker').setDate(pickedDate);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tp2MP/

Comment: If we use now or now1 the checkout calendar is poping up current month.I want calendar to popup the select date and month which will be selected in checkin date feild.

Comment: If i want to disable previous dates which was selected in checkin for checkout date popup calendar, is there any solution can you help me..

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it had help me alot.